# Use command line to call an FME workbench from a python tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, fme-form, command-line

I have a Python script that I run in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2. I also have an FME workbench I use in part of the same process. I currently have to run half of the script, switch to FME then run the other half. I would like my script to call the FMW.

At present I'm trying:

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files\\FME201864bit\\fme.exe" "W:\\Entity\\ABZ\\Operations & Geosciences\\GSR\\GIS Data\\_Common-Data\\_Resources\\Tools\\MigMapCountourFiller.fmw" --SourceDataset_ESRISHAPE "\\\\main.glb.corp.local\\Data\\EP\\EMEA\\GB\\Group\\Data\\GIS\\Explo\\NewVentures\\Opportunities\\Winterton2018\\Migration\\2018-02-14_CarbMigFiles\\contours_l_1m.shp" --DestDataset_ESRISHAPE "\\\\main.glb.corp.local\\Data\\EP\\EMEA\\GB\\Group\\Data\\GIS\\Explo\\NewVentures\\Opportunities\\Winterton2018\\Migration\\2018-02-14_CarbMigFiles"'
os.system(cmd)
```

this is returning:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable grogram or batch file. The system cannot find the path specialised.
```

I can see that the problem is the space between program and files but I dont understand why its ignoring my quotes.

I see there are multiple ways of accessing command line from python and that there is also FMEobjects but I haven't managed to get them to work. Am I trying the right thing but getting it wrong or should I be using a completely different method.

Comment: By "a python script that I run in ArcGIS Desktop", do you mean a Python Script tool in a standard TBX toolbox, or a Python Toolbox PYT tool, or something else?  In any event what code snippet are you using to try and run the two lines that you appear to have copy/pasted from your actual code?

Comment: Ultimately it will end up in a python Toolbox but at the moment I'm just trying to run these two lines by themself from python console in ArcMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managing all arguments in a single string is a debugging hell.

You would be better off using `subprocess` and having your arguments in a tidy list structure.

```
import os
import subprocess

args = [r"C:\FME\fme.exe", "version"]
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Output:

> FME 2018.0.0.0 (20180308 - Build 18284 - WIN64)

Your arguments would obviously be different. In my case, I just want to make sure the `fme.exe` is called with a single argument.

As Mark pointed out, your other option is to use `fmeobjects` which would give you ability to call your workbenches. The minimal working code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\FME\fmeobjects\python27')

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def buffer_single_shapefile_diff_param_values():  
    try:
        wkspc_path = r"C:\FMEWorkbenches\BufferForSameShapefile.fmw"

        wkspc = fmeobjects.FMEWorkspaceRunner()
        for dist in xrange(100,200,25):
            wkspc.runWithParameters(wkspc_path,
                                    {"Output_buffered_name":"Buffered_{0}m".format(dist),
                                     "OFFSET":"{0}".format(dist)})

    except fmeobjects.FMEException, err:
        print "FMEException: %s" % err
        sys.exit(1)

buffer_single_shapefile_diff_param_values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although what you are trying should work (I don't have enough Python knowledge to debug quotes) I think the better solution is to use FME Objects.

Check out the [documentation for the FMEObjects API](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/fmepython/). In particular you're looking for a method called fmeobjects.FMEWorkspaceRunner and FMEWorkspaceRunner.run(workspace)

You say you couldn't get FME Objects to work. Was there a particular issue or error? Were you using this method or something else?

Comment: I add the fmeobjects module by entering  import sys
... sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\FME201864bit\fmepython27') but then whenever I type FME objects I get NameError: name 'fmeobjects' is not defined

Comment: I think I've got it working now

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll up to the top of the log there is an example batch command for the script:

cmd = [r"C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe",
r"D:\teararoa\nz\script\ET_Node.fmw",
r"--SourceDataset_GEODATABASE_FILE d:\teararoa\nz\current.gdb",
r"--DestDataset_GEODATABASE_FILE d:\teararoa\nz\current.gdb",
r"--DestDataset_GEODATABASE_FILE_4 d:\teararoa\nz\current.gdb"]

Which I have converted to a python list and escaped the backslashes.
Then use the python module subprocess as above - easy

```
import subprocess, os
result = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
if not result.returncode:
    print("Failed!", result)
    os.startfile(r"D:\teararoa\nz\script\ET_Node.log")
else:
    print"hooray!")
```

The trouble is fme.exe **always** returns a non-zero result when you use subprocess.call()  Even if the log says it was successful with no warnings. How can I get a proper success/fail flag?
Answering my own question: use result = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
and then test NOT result.returncode for success
The reason I do this at all is because I am mixing ArcMap (32 bit) and FME 64 bit in one workflow. I don't even install fme32 now.